# delaying a method of an object with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay

I'm a jquery novice trying to write my first app here and one thing I've been trying to figure out is how to use the `.delay()` method if what I want to delay is the method of an object.

So for example, I have something like this:

```
dice = new Dice("#die1", "#die2");
dice.roll();
```

But I want there to be a delay before the `roll()` function is actually invoked.  How would I do that?

I figured using jquery would be easier than pure javascript because I know that using `setTimout()` is tricky to use with your own methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing tricky or dangerous about `setTimeout` and it's likely the most appropriate approach here.  It's specifically designed to execute functions after a given time has expired.

For example here's a 1 second delay

```
dice = new Dice("#die1", "#die2");
setTimeout(function() { dice.roll(); }, 1000);
```

Comment: Or just `setTimeout(dice.roll, 1000)` ;)

Comment: Okay, so my problem is that the setTimeout doesn't really pause the program.  It merely delays the function that is the first arugment but it runs the rest of the code in the mean time.  I need a way to actually pause the program.  Any way to do this?

Comment: @sq1020 can you be more specific by what you mean by "pause"? Do you want the website to simply hang for a few seconds or disable parts of your UI?

Comment: @JaredPar: Well, I just don't want the rest of my code to run before the delayed function finishes executing completely.  Is that possible or perhaps what I'm trying to do should be handled in a different way.  I have a dice object that rolls several times in my program and the image of the dice is updated accordingly after each roll but if there is no pause between rolls, you don't actually see the intermediate results on the site.

Comment: @sq1020 why not put the rest of your code in a function and call that function from the `setTimeout` callback?